# jquery chained remote default selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, chained

I am using Chained Selects jQuery Plugin to chain a couple of selects,

I have a remotely chained drop down where I want to select a particular option. Right now it defaults to the first one.

Any code sample is appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far

Comment: $("#deliveryState").remoteChained("#deliveryCountry",baseGetDeliveryStatesUrl)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys solved my own question, you just need to pass a additional element with a key as "selected" in the JSON response. For e.g if "7 series" needs to be selected by default then as per example below.

{ "":"--","series-1":"1 series","series-3":"3 series","series-5":"5 series","series-6":"6 series","series-7":"7 series","selected":"series-7"}